# I would like to Reverse Engineer a formula, given a set of coordinates.

Tags: functions, regression

I'm trying to find the original function without trial and error, also I know that every single function can be represented as a polynomial function but I am not looking for a best fit as much as an exact match.

[Coordinates](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Uf16ujjYTrJtxUygoqxvWMcxy26B6UmL9lUNpr7xXAg/edit#gid=0)

Aside from the list of coordinates I know that the original formula contains $\cos$ and $\pi$.

I got within a $2\%$ maximum margin of error with any given point with this formula:

$$y = \cos \frac {1000 \cdot \pi} {5975.00135 \cdot x + 999.6586074}$$

However I don't know where to go from here to make it more accurate. Let me know if there is any more information I can provide.

Edit:

It seems I left out some crucial info.

The formula is a diminishing returns formula and I am unaware of the cap.

The diminishing returns formula begins at $14444.44$ until that point it is a linear formula. the formula converts a rating into a percent value. The formula before $14444.44$ rating is...

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Rating} \cdot 0.000045 &= \mathrm{Value}\\
14444.44 \cdot 0.000045 &= 65\%
\end{align}

Beyond $14444.44$ or $65\%$ the coefficient $0.000045$ no longer applies and begins to diminish. Such that at $14125$ Rating above $14444.44$ the coefficient is $0.0000105305$.

For my formula $x$ is the percent rating above $14444.44$ while the $x$ I gave you on the spread sheet was Flat Rating above $14444.44$ (my bad)

the correct formula given $x$ on the spreadsheet would be...

$$y = \cos( 1000 π  / ( 5975.00135 ( x / 14444.44 + 1 ) + 999.6586074 ) )$$

Comment: How do you know, such a function exist?

Comment: This is the kind of problem that [Genetic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming) is very adept at solving.

Comment: Are you just trying to achieve a fit, or is there any significance to the values of your fitting function at the x values between the nodes? For just achieving a fit, you could just do least squares on a basic form (e.g. polynomial) and see what you get. In this case it seems natural to try to make the function in question be increasing and concave, so perhaps you could try to fit it to a power law with an exponent between 0 and 1?

Comment: Followup: apparently the log-log plot is *also* increasing and concave, so your function ultimately grows slower than any power law. Do you have reason to think your function is bounded, or might it not be bounded? (Also, I don't understand how your formula gets the result you've written. Perhaps you mean $1000 \pi \cos(...)$?)